# how to use varray to recieve multiple arguments in oracle function

Tags: oracle, plsql, varray

I want to create a function which will take multiple arguments in varray and return the greatest value of that varray, like greatest() function do in oracle. Arguments may contain all number or text. I'm thinking about using a varray of number or text type but don't know how to properly declare them in function definition and how to access all the elements on it to find out the greatest one.

I know greatest() function is available by default, but I want it as user defined function, say, greatest_wrapper(). Anything on how do I use this varray to accept arguments and processing them will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Note that the `varray` type is only useful when you need the `limit` clause, otherwise the nested table collection type (`table of number` etc) is generally more flexible and has more features.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS005)

By the way here is an example how you can get greatest value from collection without defining a new function:

```
SQL> create type my_num_type as varray(30) of number
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> select max(column_value) from table(my_num_type(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

MAX(COLUMN_VALUE)
-----------------
                5

1 row selected.
```